# By-name parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, pass-by-name

From book 'Programming in Scala':

```
var assertionsEnabled = true
def myAssert(predicate: () => Boolean) =
if (assertionsEnabled && !predicate())
throw new AssertionError

myAssert(() => 5 > 3)
```

Using empty parameter list is awkward.
Scala provides by-name parameter to solve this.

```
def byNameAssert(predicate: => Boolean) =
if (assertionsEnabled && !predicate)
throw new AssertionError

byNameAssert(5 > 3)
```

I have a confusion in this discussion.myAssert takes in a parameter which is a function, which in turn takes no parameter and returns a boolean.

What is input type for byNameAssert?Is it same as myAssert?To me,it seems an expression which evaluates to a boolean value, and having it in by-name form means that expression is evaluated whenever it is called and not  when being passed to byNameAssert.But then it is not same as input type of myAssert. And if that is the case, then byNameAssert and myAssert are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

> To me,it seems an expression which evaluates to a boolean value, and having it in by-name form means that expression is evaluated whenever it is called and not when being passed to byNameAssert.

Yes. But the way it's implemented is that Scala compiles `byNameAssert` and `myAssert` to exactly the same code (except for different `@ScalaSignature` annotation) and whenever it sees calls like `byNameAssert(5 > 3)` they are rewritten so the next compiler stage sees the argument as `() => 5 > 3` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> What is input type for byNameAssert?

`=> Boolean`

> Is it same as myAssert?

No, `myAssert` expects `() => Boolean` as argument. While "morally the same", it is treated as a separate type by the compiler.

The `=> Boolean`-thing is neither `() => Boolean`, nor `Boolean`. The following little example is supposed to further illustrate that. Trying to assign curried `foo` to variables of type `() => Boolean` and `Boolean` fails:

```
scala> def foo(b: => Boolean): Unit = {}
foo: (b: => Boolean)Unit

scala> val f: Boolean => Unit = foo _
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (=> Boolean) => Unit
 required: Boolean => Unit
       val f: Boolean => Unit = foo _
                                ^

scala> val f: (() => Boolean) => Unit = foo _
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (=> Boolean) => Unit
 required: (() => Boolean) => Unit
       val f: (() => Boolean) => Unit = foo _
                                        ^
```

But this works:

```
scala> val f: (=> Boolean) => Unit = foo _
f: (=> Boolean) => Unit = $$Lambda$1090/668948486@69bc9584
```

So, while `=> Boolean` is essentially the same as `() => Boolean` from the point of view of the implementation, it is treated separately as a different type, and it behaves quite differently when it comes to syntactic desugaring of expressions and code blocks passed as arguments to functions.