# Trying to understand this scala notation

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and while was trying to understand implicits in Scala, I am getting hard time understand **[A](f: => A)** part. Can any one explain please?

```
object Helpers {
 implicit class IntWithTimes(x: Int) {
  def times[A](f: => A): Unit = {
  def loop(current: Int): Unit =
    if(current > 0) {
      f
      loop(current - 1)
    }
  loop(x)
}
```

}
}

This is being called as:

```
scala> import Helpers._
import Helpers._

scala> 5 times println("HI")
      HI
      HI
      HI
      HI
      HI
```

Reference : https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of Scala by-name parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663219/use-of-scala-by-name-parameters)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707521/by-name-parameter-in-scala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/how-to-use-by-name-parameters-scala-functions
https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala/simple-scala-call-name-example
https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/26/call-by-name.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's disect this method declaration:

```
def times[A](f: => A): Unit
```

- `def`: keyword used to define a method
- `times`: method name
- `[A]`: a **type parameter** named A. This means that this method takes a type parameter which can be passed either explicitly (e.g. by calling `times[Int](...)`) or implicitly (calling `times(...)` and letting compiler infer the type) when the method is called. See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html for more details
- `(f: => A)`: these are the method's "value parameters", in this case there's exactly one such parameter, named `f`, of type `A` (which is the type parameter we've declared!). The `=>` signifies that this parameter is a **call-by-name** parameter, see https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html
- `: Unit`: this is the method's return type - defined to be `Unit`, practically meaning this method doesn't return any value